# How to implement Angular AuthGuard that uses CanMatchFn and CanActivateFn? (How to convert Class Guards to Functional Guards)

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15

I have the following Angular AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    ): | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        return this.isAuthenticated();
    }

    canLoad(
        route: Route,
        segments: UrlSegment[],
    ): | boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
        return this.isAuthenticated();
    }

    isAuthenticated(): | boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
        return this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
            take(1),
            tap((isAuthenticated: boolean) => {
                if (!isAuthenticated) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
                }
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

I updated to Angular 15:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.0
Node: 16.19.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 15.2.0

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.0
@schematics/angular             15.2.0
```

And now I'm getting the following TS depreciation note:
[image]
And a similar depreciation message for the CanLoad interface:

```
@deprecated — Use CanMatchFn instead
'CanLoad' is deprecated.
```

I tried to look for how to implement my AuthGuard with the recommended `CanActivateFn` and `CanMatchFn`, but I couldn't find a good resource on you to implement this with the ability to redirect to a certain route when the user is not authenticated, as it appears in the old CanActivate and CanLoad implementation above:

```
this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
```

How to correctly implement a simple Angular AuthGuard that uses the new `CanMatchFn` and `CanActivateFn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use `inject(AuthGuard).canActivate` as `CanActivateFn`.

If you want to refactor to drop the class it's similar :

```
const isAuthenticated = (): | boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> => {
    const authService = inject(AuthService);
    const router = inject(Router);
    return authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
        take(1),
        tap((isAuthenticated: boolean) => {
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
            }
        }),
    );
}

const canActivate:CanActivateFn = isAuthenticated;
const canMatch:CanMatchFn = isAuthenticated;
```

For the depreciation of `CanLoad` just pass `canMatch: [canMatch]` in your router.

---

Edit: For futur references, [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48709/files) adds new helper functions to allow smooth migration from Class guard to functionnal guards.

- `mapToCanActivate([MyClassGuard])`
- `mapToCanActivateChild([MyClassGuard])`
- `mapToCanMatch([MyClassGuard])`

etc. This will probably land in 15.3 or 16.0.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Any idea why did the Angular team change the implementation from using the regular DI in an injectable class to using manual injection?

Comment: You might want to read https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/47924

Comment: By the way I added the new helper functions that will land in the next minor release !

Comment: Can we replace here 'const' with 'export'?  should we? Also, what do you do if that helper function isAuthenticated() is async and has some 'await' inside?

Comment: @user1981152 The API supported returning Promises/Observable so no issue and yes you can export them to use them is other files !